# Remove 1 Disk From 4 Disk RAID 5 Array

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

Im using a PERC 3/DC controller to run a RAID 5 array using 4 hard disks.
I am hoping to change this to 3 disks in the array and 1 hot spare.
Is it possible to remove 1 disk from the array, reconfigure it as a hot spare, then reconfigure the RAID 5 array to use 3 disks WITHOUT loosing any data?
I have backups but I would rather just reconfigure it without going through the hassle of restoring data.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and if you have 4 disks and want two spares you are better off performance wise with a 4 disk RAID 10 instead of a 3 disk RAID 5 + hot spare. Either way your array will have 2 disks worth of usable capacity but the RAID 10 will have better write speeds and takes less time to recover from a failed disk.

Assuming the RAID 5 doesn't contain your boot volume, I'd go ahead and backup the data, reconfigure to a RAID 10, and restore the data.

```
    RAID Level Comparison for arrays up to 8 drives.
Features                RAID 0  RAID 1   RAID 5   RAID 6   RAID 10
Min Drives                2       2        3        4        4
Data Protection           0       1        1        2        2 (Up to one disk failure in each sub-array)
Read Performance         High    High     High     High     High
Write Performance        High   Medium    Low      Low     Medium
Degraded Read Perf       N/A    Medium    Low      Low      High
Degraded Write Perf      N/A     High     Low      Low      High
Capacity Utilization %   100     50      67-87    50-75     50
```

Comment: +1 Agree. Many people don't event think about raid 10, but in some situations is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions, and thanks for the RAID 10 idea, it hadnt even crossed my mind.
Il get on it first thing Monday.